# My question has been put "on hold" and I have edited it. Now what?

Tags: feature-request

I asked a question that has been put on hold because it was considered EOL. Here it goes: [Backup with Deja-dup: keep records to keep history vs keep lastest backup to save memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998082/backup-with-deja-dup-keep-records-to-keep-history-vs-keep-lastest-backup-to-sav). I have edited the question to make it fit. I wish I could indicate to the members that have flaged my question that it was edited and now it should be good to go.

Do we have this feature on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the question can be flagged for moderator assistance, but that's inappropriate with this question. You should ask a new question since the edit changed the nature of the question. I added [the following comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998082/is-it-necessary-to-keep-records-of-my-backups#comment1612949_998082) to that question to explain:

> It's not really allowed to change a question so that good answers are no longer good answers. Since this is now Déjà Dup-specific and invalidates the accepted answer, you should ask a new question instead of editing this question. I've reverted your edit, and you can [click here to see the newer version of your question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/68cedd77-27ad-49c8-8e1b-f4fda095117c/view-source) so that you can re-ask it (the newer question title is `Backup with Deja-dup: keep records to keep history vs keep lastest backup to save memory?`).

[This question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286803/379373) goes a bit into the changing the nature of questions.